# What are the rules for coupling a ViewModel and a View in the MVVM pattern?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

So given the *Separation of Concerns*, how coupled should the View and ViewModel be?

For example, I want the visibility of a Control in the View to be databound (databinded?) to a flag in the ViewModel.

My first hunch would be to use a boolean value, `IsControlVisible` that returns true/false. However, in the View, visibility is set by an Enum.

So I have a choice: change the property to an Enum, or use a Converter to convert the bool into the Visibility Enum.

**Which is the proper approach when trying to follow idiomatic MVVM?**

Comment: Data bound is correct, not data binded ;-)

Comment: 2 votes for off-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the View-Model is only concerned with a control being visible or collapsed, then I'd make it a boolean and use a value converter. If the View-Model also needs to communicate the hidden state, then I'd make it an enum (and probably use the Visibility enum).

So to answer your question, I'd have the View-Model express what it needs (visible/collapsed or visible/collapsed/hidden) and adapt the View to fit with the value converter. Other cases may vary though, as with most things.

Comment: Why does he need a converter?  That's just creating more work for no benefit.

Comment: @subt13 - There is actually a built in converter for just this case (BooleanToVisibilityConverter). It makes the View-Model much clearer, especially if the Hidden state is not valid. By using an Enum, your VM can be invalid.

Comment: DOH. I just wrote my own like 5 minutes ago :) Thanks!

Comment: @CodeNaked - I guess it depends on what he needs.  The "cleanest" way is to use a simple property that matches the type of property he wants to bind too.  Sure if he needs to take in a set of unique values and **convert** them to a valid Visibility value then a converter would be cleaner.

Comment: @subt13 - I disagree. Having a property that matches type is not the cleanest way. Let's say you have an IsError property and you want to display something in Bold when that is true. Under your model, you'd have to have an ErrorFontWeight property. Whereas the best way to do that would be through a value converter or trigger.

Comment: @CodeNaked - I think you may have misunderstood my last comment.  In any case, for the details he provided in his question a value converter is way overkill.  If he follows your approach he is going to have a potential maintenance nightmare of value converters to have to deal with.

Comment: @CodeNaked: It looks like that Boolean converter isn't available in Silverlight.

Comment: @Alan - Ah, sorry was in WPF land. You're right, I believe I just duplicated that in a shared library since it was used so much.

Comment: @subt13 - Possibly, but in general the VM shouldn't be adapted to fit the View, it should be the other way around.

Comment: +1 A converter would be what I would recommend too. It allows you to keep your view and viewModel separate and makes it easier to replace the front-end if needed (say a web-app in asp.net using the existing viewmodels). You might also want to do a DataTrigger based on the value, in which case its much better to keep it as a boolean.

Comment: @Rachel - and a property in the viewmodel doesn't keep the view and view model separate?  Please explain how that works.  BTW - have you ever  tried to port a WPF converter to a silverlight one?  Good luck.

Comment: @subt13 A property in the ViewModel is tied to the view if it uses View-specific language such as a Visibility Enum. A boolean is a value that can be used by any View, not just a WPF or Silverlight View. It also allows you to use the IsVisible property for bindings that are not Visibility properties, such as DataTriggers to determine Height/Width, Color, Font, etc. Converters are extremely simple to create. I have made many converters for both WPF and Silverlight, and yes, I have converted WPF converters to Silverlight ones. In most cases, I don't even need to change anything.

Comment: @Rachel - It is obvious you have way more experience in WPF than Silverlight.  It is also apparent that you make up things as you go, such as "view-specific language" (please don't take offense).  Look Silverlight is a subset of WPF and hence your value converters will not port so well, unless they are very basic.  A property on the otherhand requires no porting, no extra class, no extra confusion, and no extra-maintenance.

Comment: @subt13 When I said View-Specific, I meant doing something like using an ASP.Net View for the front-end instead of Silverlight/WPF. MVVM doesn't have to be limited to WPF/Silverlight. Most Value Converters I have ported over from WPF to Silverlight have gone over fine. I still prefer a boolean property over an enum because I find them simpler to use and they can be easily used in DataTriggers or other Value Converters, not just the Visibility property.

Comment: @Rachel - fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

The question you need to ask is "why is this widget being hidden?"

If the answer is because it's not available, your VM property should probably be a `bool` called `IsAvailable`. If it's because some other property has or doesn't have a particular value, do it with an `IValueConverter`.

The general concept is that the VM holds the *conceptual* state of the system, and the View decides how to visually represent that.

Answer (score 2):

Your ViewModel could expose property of type Visibility instead of a bool and bind directly to that.